# What is the meaning of かない here?

Tags: meaning, translation

a guy is hungry and says to his 4 friends:
腹減ったな　何か食ってかない

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is simply a contraction of [食]{く}って[い]{L}かない, which of course is, "Should(n't) we go get something to eat?".

See also [～ましょうか　vs　～ませんか](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/56124/78).